# how to get all the values of objects on javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have object like this:

```
[
  {
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "gps.positions",
    "fields": {
      "power": null,
       "altitude": null,
      "time": "2014-04-08T04:00:00Z",
      "longitude": 47.916142,
      "course": null,
      "other": "",
      "device": 11,
      "address": "test",
      "latitude": 29.30661,
      "speed": null,
      "valid": null
    }
  },
  {
    "pk": 3,
    "model": "gps.positions",
    "fields":{
      "power": null,
      "altitude": null,
      "time": "2014-04-08T20:00:00Z",
      "longitude": 47.91,
      "course": null,
      "other": "",
      "device": 11,
      "address": "test2",
      "latitude": 29.30661,
      "speed": null,
      "valid": null
    }
  }
]
```

I want to get values like this:

```
pk  fields.power   etc.
2    null
3    null

for(var i=0; i<data.length, i++){
    data[i].pk   //returns only one value i.e 3
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? You are already getting value in `data[i]` which is an object.

Comment: As you can see `pk` has two values `2 and 3`, I am getting only `3`

Comment: Explain exactly what you want to achieve, it isn't clear

Comment: thats when your `i==1`. When `i==0`, first looping, then you get `2` as a value.

Comment: I see that your code is working, I got the two values "2" and "3"

Comment: check this  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/cLTGh/

Comment: Apparently, it's working. Sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score -1):

```
var o = <your object>

var i, l;
for (i = 0, l = o.length; i < l; i += 1) {
  console.log(o[i].pk, o[i].fields.power);
}
```